# How current flows in a transformer?

Tags: electromagnetism

I came across this statement in a textbook saying, $$\text{"An inductor blocks AC but it allows DC"}$$

Then in case of a transformer , how current flows through the primary and secondary coils of the transformer?

I also came across this statement saying, $$\text{"The two coils of the transformer are magnetically linked via transformer core"}$$ What does this mean? Is there any link between this statement and the flow of current in the two coils?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/766089/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*An inductor blocks AC but it allows DC.*
For an ideal inductor replace the word *blocks* with *impedes*.

*The two coils of the transformer are magnetically linked via transformer core*
What happens to the current / voltage in one coil is connected to what is happening to the voltage / current in the the other coil via a magnetic field in the transformer core.